# Не работает login в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Пытаюсь на сайте войти на обычного зарегистрированного пользователя на сайте, всё работает через login, пробовал разные способы, ничего не получается, заходит только на суперюзера

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class RegForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def clean(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
      raise forms.ValidationError('Данный почтовый адрес уже зарегистрирован')
    return self.cleaned_data

  class Meta:
    model = User  
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email','password']
    widgets = {
      'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder' : 'Имя',
        'required' : True
      }),
      'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder' : 'Фамилия',
        'required' : True
      }),
      'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'placeholder' : 'Email',
        'required' : True
      }),
      'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder' : 'Пароль',
        'required' : True
      })
    }

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def clean(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    password = self.cleaned_data['password']
    if not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
      raise forms.ValidationError(f'Пользователь с таким email не найден')
    user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
    if user:
      if not user.check_password(password):
        raise forms.ValidationError('Неверный пароль')

    return self.cleaned_data

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['email', 'password']
    widgets = {
      'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'placeholder' : 'Email',
        'required' : True
      }),
      'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder' : 'Пароль',
        'required' : True
      })
    }
 
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import RegForm, LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def reg(request):
  try:
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
  except:
    if request.method == 'POST':
      form_reg = RegForm(request.POST)
      if form_reg.is_valid():
        new_user = User.objects.create(
          username = form_reg.cleaned_data['email'],
          email = form_reg.cleaned_data['email'],
          first_name = form_reg.cleaned_data['first_name'],
          last_name = form_reg.cleaned_data['last_name'],
          password = form_reg.cleaned_data['password']
        )
        login(request, new_user)
        return redirect('account')

      context = {
        'form': form_reg,
      }

      return render(request, 'reglog/reg.html', context)

    else:
      form_reg = RegForm()
      context = {
        'form': form_reg
      }
      return render(request, 'reglog/reg.html', context)
  else:
    return redirect('account')

def log(request):
  try:
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
  except:
    if request.method == 'POST':
      form_log = LoginForm(request.POST)
      if form_log.is_valid():
        email = form_log.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form_log.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=email, email=email, password=password)
        if user:
          login(request, user)
          return redirect('account')
        
      context = {
        'form': form_log,
      }

      return render(request, 'reglog/log.html', context)
    
    else:
      form_log = LoginForm()
      context = {
      'form': form_log,
      }
      return render(request, 'reglog/log.html', context)
  else:
    return redirect('account')
```

После нажатия по вход вылетает ошибка из forms.py(пароль ввожу верно): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В общем ошибку нашёл в сохранении юзера, просто if form_reg.is_valid() переписал так:

```
if form_reg.is_valid():
        new_user = form_reg.save(commit=False)
        new_user.username = form_reg.cleaned_data['email']
        new_user.email = form_reg.cleaned_data['email']
        new_user.first_name = form_reg.cleaned_data['first_name']
        new_user.last_name = form_reg.cleaned_data['last_name']
        new_user.save()
        new_user.set_password(form_reg.cleaned_data['password'])
        new_user.save()
        login(request, new_user)
        return redirect('account')
```

И всё стало работать. В админке смутило, что у юзеров в пароле было это: *Неизвестный формат пароля или алгоритм хеширования* и я решил переписать и всё стало работать прекрасно, в общем проблема была в паролях

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать данную инструкцию

[Создание log-in view](https://pocoz.gitbooks.io/django-v-primerah/content/glava-4-sozdanie-social-website/ispolzovanie-django-authentication-framework/sozdanie-log-in-view.html)

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло